# Spring prototype beans with parameters?

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean, prototype-scope

Is it possible to define a **prototype bean**, using XML config or annotation-based config such that I can get an instance of the bean with a custom parameter value? My use case is a message queue handler that makes API calls with different parameter values that are supplied in the inbound message.

In this case it seems I can do one of two things:

- Get an instance of my prototype-scope bean and then call setters to customize it to be specific to the inbound message.
- Construct a new instance of the bean class using a plain `new MyPrototypeBean()` and then call setters to customize the instance.

Perhaps a different way of wording my question is: What is the benefit of using a prototype-scope bean vs. using a simple Java constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a prototype bean from another bean while passing arguments to constructor you can use `<lookup-method>` (XML Configuration) or `@Lookup` (annotation-based configuration).

If you want to get the prototype instance from "unmanaged" code (not from a bean) *or* you don't want to use the lookup methods, you can achieve the same using `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory.getBean(String beanName, Object...)`.

Answering your second question, difference between a prototype-scope bean and using a simple Java constructor is that the prototype-scope bean still have access to Spring container's features. This includes, but it's not limited to the following: it can have collaborators provided in XML configuration (`<property name="someCollaborator" ref="..."/>`) or with annotations (`@Resource`, `@Autowired`, ...), t can implement Spring-aware interfaces (like `ApplicationContextAware` so that the prototype bean itself has access to the container).

Comment: Thanks, and can you edit your answer to put the `@Lookup` method paragraph first? Pivotal Support confirmed your answer and said that `@Lookup` is the better approach, presumably for the same reason you cited above.

Comment: Thanks, i've rearranged the answer accordingly.

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen I have to implement something similar. How can i pass an oject at runtime to a prototype bean 
which I am getting from  Spring Service Locator. The Service Locator method just takes a String argument which is basically 
a mapping to the spring bean id/name.

Comment: @bluelurker sorry, but i don't know what Spring Service Locator is.

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen  this: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/ServiceLocatorFactoryBean.html